# This question has been asked before, but the older question doesn't have an answer

Tags: discussion

The question [Why is my car tramlining(pulling/veering when I hit road imperfections)?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/15711/why-is-my-car-tramliningpulling-veering-when-i-hit-road-imperfections) has been voted to be closed because there is an older question [How do I prevent bushing wear and what parts besides the suspension uses bushings?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/15234/how-do-i-prevent-bushing-wear-and-what-parts-besides-the-suspension-uses-bushing).

Note the following statement provided for voting to close questions as duplicates:

> **duplicate:** This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

The older question in this case does not have an answer. I have seen this before on MV&M, so I would like to draw attention to:

> ## ...**already has an answer.**

It seems like the appropriate way to handle the scenario would be to mark the *older* question as a duplicate since the newer question has answers.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: The two question you have linked to are not duplicates (IMHO)

Comment: @Movemorecommentslinktotop I agree, but this isn't the first time I have seen this, which is why I didn't address that part of this specific example in my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close voting is actually prevented [if the "master" question is unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165933/changes-to-close-as-duplicate).* The exception is when the posts are **by the same author**, as these are. Otherwise, the close vote dialog would not have allowed the vote to be cast:

[image: Close vote dialog with disabled "Vote to Close" button and warning message "This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer"]

The exception is a small check against double-posting: someone asking a question, then asking the same thing again an hour or a day later. (This guard is much more necessary on larger sites than on a growing beta like this one, but it applies across SE regardless.)

I assume that the close voter believed that this was essentially a double-post: a new/revised question on the same issue. I won't argue that belief one way or the other, but close voting is the correct choice if you believe that. The author should edit the original rather than reposting.

I will also point out that the newer question was answered nearly two days *after* the close vote was cast.

---

*Where "unanswered" is actually defined as "no answer that's upvoted or accepted".

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, although it seems peculiar that I've seen this before on this site.